# convert all dates in a column to numbers

Tags: excel, time, numbers, date-conversion

I'm trying to convert time to numbers in excel. I am using this formula:

```
=HOUR(A2) + MINUTE(A2) / 60 + SECOND(A2) / 3600
```

And it works well, but I have to convert a column with around 65.000 of dates.
How do I do that in an elegant and time saving way?

Comment: `=MOD(A2,1)*24` will return the same result. Then just fill down as suggested by @Stergios

Comment: Thank you :D I did it in Excel. Now the only struggle is how to do it on Mac, because that double click thing doesn't work in Numbers, Mac.

Comment: I suggest you post that question in an Apple/Numbers forum.  Numbers and Excel are two different programs. But I believe there are auto-fill options in the Table menu of Numbers that should be able to do what you want; or perhaps you can create a Table, as you can in Excel.  Then when you enter a formula in the first data row, it might auto-populate down.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea :) I found it. It's Table > Autofill Cells > Autofill Down. It's applying the formula downwards for each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming that your formula does what you want it to do, you just have to double click on the lower-right part on the cell with your first formula. So if your data are in the range A2:A65000, write your formula on cell B2, and double click on its lower-right part.

See the pic below:

[image]

Comment: Yes :D Thank you. I tried in Excel and it works! It does not work on Mac. I wanted to try there too :)

Answer (score 0):

Assume you mean time rather than date.
Try
=A2*24
Format as general

To apply to a large range you can put 24 into a spare cell, copy it, select range you want to convert to number and paste special... Then select multiply and okay.

Comment: Yes, I actually meant time, sorry. Yes, it works in excel :) thank you. I tried the same in Numbers on Mac and it did not work :P Numbers does not have Paste Special